# Running multiple versions of Chrome

Tags: linux, google-chrome

Is it possible to run multiple different versions of simultaneously on Linux?  I know I can do this with Firefox using the `-no-remote -P` switches but what about Google Chrome?

Answer (score 2):

A simple hack is to use Chrome's Incognito mode <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>.

You can run Chrome using different profiles by using the `--user-data-dir` flag. For example, save this script as `chrome.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
  echo "Usage: $0 profile_name"
  exit 1
fi
PROFILE_NAME="$1"
GOOGLE_CHROME="/usr/local/bin/chromium"
USER_DIR=~/.config/chromium/"${PROFILE_NAME}"

exec "$GOOGLE_CHROME" \
  --enable-udd-profiles \
  --user-data-dir="$USER_DIR"
```

Create a new folder such as `~/.config/chromium/test`.

You can use the newly created profile by running `./chrome.sh test`.

Answer (score 0):

You can run instances of both Chrome and Chromium (the open source version of Chrome).

Comment: I dont think thats what jldupont meant.

Comment: I do that already but I need more. BTW, the Chromium build for Ubuntu 10.10 crashes too often for me and I don't want to bother compiling it from source every now and then.